# AppGyver steroids app - How to add scrolling to a Drawer

Tags: angularjs, navigation-drawer, hybrid-mobile-app, steroids, appgyver

I implemented a drawer in my [steroids](http://www.appgyver.io/steroids) application with similar styles as google+ drawer. However, I have several links on it, and when my device is in landscape mode I'm unable to see all the links, and I can't scroll the drawer.

I want to be able to scroll the drawer vertically as a normal webview, just like google+ drawer does.

Is that possible?

Can I embed a webview inside another?

[image: Landscape screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this by adding `heigh=device-height` to the content meta tag. And I added `overflow-x=hidden` to just allow vertical scrolling.